# How can I replace various parts of a string in the same line?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, replace

I have these string:

```
Database_123456.bak
```

I need to take only the number:

```
123456
```

I do this:

```
 Dim number As String = Replace("Database_123456.bak", "Database", "")
```

This return me:

```
123456.bak
```

And I have to add another variable to replace again the last part:

```
Dim FinalNumber as string = Replace(number, ".bak", "")
```

Is there any way to replace the two parts in the same line, to abbreviate?

thanks

Comment: DIY :  useful link - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59488/extract-numbers-from-an-alphanumeric-string

Comment: You might rely on `Split` (on one of the overloads accepting more than one separator, account for "_" and "." and take the second element of the resulting array).

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Regex:

```
Dim x As String = "Database_123456.bak"
Dim res = Integer.Parse(Regex.Replace(x, "[^\d]", ""))
```

or simply

```
Dim res = Regex.Matches("Database_123456.bak", "\d+")
```

Also you have to import

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter but your code doesn't compile. `As output` doesn't make any sense; `Dim res =` would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain replacements together using `[String].Replace`, so you can do it all in one line:

```
Dim finalNumber = "Database_123456.bak".Replace("Database_", "").Replace(".bak", "")
```

note: you missed out an underscore char in your first replacement example

To improve this you probably want to look at `Integer.TryParse` to check if the result is actually an integer or not. Something like this:

```
    Dim inputString As String = "Database_123456.bak"
    Dim finalNumber As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(inputString.Replace("Database_", "").Replace(".bak", ""), finalNumber) Then
        MessageBox.Show("The final number is " & finalNumber)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("The string is not in the correct format")
    End If
```

Also take care with upper and lower casing as replace is case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly this will work out for you

```
string text = "Database_123456.bak";

string number = text.Split('_')[1].Split('.')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       string str = "Database_123456.bak";

        string exteractNumber = string.Empty;

        foreach (char c in str.ToCharArray())
        {
            int result;
            if (int.TryParse(c.ToString(), out result))
            {
                exteractNumber = exteractNumber + c;
            }               
        }
```

Comment: Moreover, it's a code-only answer which is also bad.